# sending data from Raspberry pi 4 to firebase firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to send data from raspberry pi 4 to firebase firestore, here is the code

```
import firebase_admin
from  firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
#from google.cloud import firestore

# initializations 

cred = credentials.Certificate("/home/pi/Desktop/qu-evergreen-firebase-adminsdk-pcu2s-73526791b5.json")
#firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()


#adding first data
doc_ref = db.collection('employee').document('empdoc')

doc_ref.set({

    'name':'Try',
    'lname':'??',
    'age':25


})
```

And here is the problem that I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Senior $  /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3.10 /home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1814523869/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 40063 -- /home/pi/Senior/test1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.cloud import firestore # pylint: disable=import-error,no-name-in-module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import __version__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1._helpers import GeoPoint
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.api_core import gapic_v1  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Senior/test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import firestore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure '
ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.
```

I tried many solutions like
1- pip install grpcio
2- pip install google-cloud-core
3- pip install google-cloud-firestore
4- pip install firebase-admin
5- Updated python to latest version
And I still get the same error so any one can help

Comment: Are you able to compile grpcio from source? `pip uninstall grpcio && pip install grpcio --no-binary`

Answer (score 0):

Google firestore is not compatible with a 32-bit OS. You might want to try the new Bullseye 64-bit OS. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian version 10 is based on debian 10, which uses glibc 2.28. You cannot update easily update glibc. install OS based on debian 11

Answer (score 0):

Same question here: [Fail to import cloud firestore in python on raspberry pi 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237934/fail-to-import-cloud-firestore-in-python-on-raspberry-pi-4)

RPi 4B with Raspberry Pi SO v10 (buster) and Python 3.7.3 is NOT compatible with Firebase Python module as is.
See:

```bash
$ python3 my_firestore_script.py
...
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ...)
ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.
```

Running the command below confirms that the GLIBC is in version 2.28 (not the 2.29 as required by our script that uses firebase-admin
Python module).

```bash
$ ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10+rpt2+rpi1+deb10u1) 2.28
```

Solution options:

- use container (recommended): [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) + [python](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/python) image + `pip install firebase-admin` . Just it and have fun!
- install a newer Python version and downgrade `grpcio` module (from version 1.48 to 1.44). See [here](https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/T91EyO81c8I/m/F4YJRpqSAwAJ). Steps below.

1. Install a newer Python version. Suggestion: 3.10.4.
   Howto: https://allurcode.com/install-latest-version-of-python-on-raspberry-pi/
2. With the recent installed Python version, install `firebase-admin` module.

```bash
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 install firebase-admin
```

3. Check current version of `grpcio` installed module.

```bash
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 list  |  grep grpcio
grpcio                   1.48.1
```

4. Uninstall and install other version. Be patient because the installation takes at least 20min.

```bash
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 uninstall grpcio
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 uninstall grpcio-status
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 install grpcio==1.44.0 --no-binary=grpcio
```

5. Check again the installed modules list.

```bash
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 list  |  grep grpcio
grpcio                   1.44.0
```

6. Try again script execution.

```bash
$ python3 my_firestore_script.py
```

Now, script executes like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful just uninstalling `grpcio` with:

```
pip uninstall grpcio
```

and reinstalling `firebase-admin` again, which automatically installed `grpcio` and `google-cloud-firestore` with:

```
pip install firebase-admin
```